# Translation of くらい in this sentence?

Tags: translation, usage

I'm looking at this sentence, ここに一日中いてもいいくらいだ。 And I'm struggling to think of what "くらいだ" means here. A bunch of translators are telling me it's like "could" as in, "I *could* stay here all day" or "It would be nice to stay here all day." Is this correct? I would think dropping くらいだ and just going with ここに一日中いてもいい would suffice for "I could stay here all day." Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That くらいだ  roughly means "Is good **to the extent** of not minding being here all day" That might sound sarcastic depending on how you see it.